# Systemd: provide password noninteractively to homectl

Tags: linux, systemd, ansible

I would like to activate a systemd-homed home via ansible, how can I provide the password to the systemd password agent programmatically?

It seems that I cannot simply pipe the password to homectl activate directly...

```
$ echo $PASSWORD | homectl activate $USER

Broadcast message from root@...:

Password entry required for 'Please enter password for user user:' (PID 1319).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any way to pass the password to `homectl unlock` however ansible can provide a password to `su`, provide the `--login` option to `su` which makes it invoke pam, which will in turn unlock the systemd home directory.

When not using ansible, a construct like `cat "${passwordfile}" | sudo -Siu "${user}" COMMAND` should work similarly.

In my ansible playbook, to prevent uneccessary unmounting and remounting, I chose to set a lock on the home directory. Also I chose to run all commands that act on the users home in a su login shell too; YMMV:

```
- name: act in users homedir
  become: true
  become_user: "{{user.name}}"
  become_method: su
  become_flags: '--login'
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: "{{user.password}}"
  block:
  - name: lock user dir to prevent home unmount
    command: "flock -x -w 10 \"/home/{{user}}\" -c 'sleep 600'"
# ...
  always:
    - name: Release the lock
      command: "killall -u {{user}} flock"
      ignore_errors: true
```

If you don't want to become user for actions performed within the systemd home, this could be an alternative:

```
# Note: The user directory will unmount automatically after 600s.
# Change to 'sleep infinity' if this bothers you.
- name: act in users homedir
  block:
  - name: lock user dir to prevent home unmount
    command: "flock -x -w 10 \"/home/{{user}}\" -c 'sleep 600'"
    become: true
    become_user: "{{user.name}}"
    become_method: su
    become_flags: '--login'
    vars:
      ansible_become_pass: "{{user.password}}"
# ...
  always:
    - name: Release the lock
      command: "killall -u {{user}} flock"
      ignore_errors: true
```

Answer (score -1):

[man homectl](https://man.archlinux.org/man/homectl.1.en) ... look for `--identity` ... it doesn't accept passwords from stdin, but does accept the hash from a json file.

Comment: `homectl --identity=FILE USER` simply ignores FILE. It is only documented for use with create and update but I want to activate a home.